# La consulta SELECT no me devuelve nada

Tags: php, mysql, date

estoy intentando hacer una consulta a una base de datos con un criterio de selección de fechas y no me devuelve nada. Me podrían ayudar?

En la base de datos MySQL tengo el campo Fecha Emision como DATE
Este es el codigo que pongo

```
<?php
          $Ing_tot = "SELECT  SUM(Total) AS suma_tot FROM FACTURAS WHERE Fecha Emision BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'";
          $res_Ing_tot = mysqli_query($conexion, $Ing_tot);
          $Show_Ing_tot = mysqli_fetch_array($res_Ing_tot);
          echo "$Show_Ing_tot[suma_tot]" . " €";
    ?>
```

Comment: Considera cambiar el nombre de la columna para que no tenga espacios, por lo pronto intenta agregar comillas en la consulta `'Fecha Emision'`; pero mi recomendación es que lo cambies a `fecha_emision`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html):

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (`):
>
> ---
>
> El carácter de identificación es la comilla invertida (`)

Esta debe usarse para identificar elementos que son declarados usando palabras reservadas o elementos con caracteres especiales o con espacios. Tal es el caso de tu columna `Fecha Emision`.

Si es posible, recomendaría, como ha comentado  @JonathanOrta, que cambies el nombre de esa columna y de todas aquellas que tengan espacios en blanco, letras como `ñ` o palabras acentuadas, etc.  Si no puedes hacerlo, cada consulta que escribas tienes que poner este tipo de columnas rodeado de comillas invertidas, algo así:

```
SELECT  ...  FROM FACTURAS WHERE `Fecha Emision` ...
```

En cuanto al código PHP, sugiero que uses métodos más específicos para obtener los datos. Si lees el Manual de PHP verás que `mysqli_fetch_array()` devuelve los resultados dos veces: como array numérico y como array asociativo. Dado que usas el modo asociativo en la lectura, entonces usa directamente [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

```
$Ing_tot = "SELECT  SUM(Total) AS suma_tot FROM FACTURAS WHERE `Fecha Emision` BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'";
$res_Ing_tot = mysqli_query($conexion, $Ing_tot);
$Show_Ing_tot = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_Ing_tot);
echo "$Show_Ing_tot[suma_tot]" . " €";
```

Si no hay otros errores, tu código debería funcionar.